# Assign multiple classes to html elements using helpers

Tags: css, cakephp

For an application I am building in CakePHP I want to use a third party CSS template (Pure-CSS). The template is designed such that every now and then I have to assign multiple classes to a single element. At many places I am using CakePHP helpers, eg. for generating forms. I can't figure out how to assign more than one class using these helpers:

```
//this works (only one class)
echo $this->Form->create('Profile',array('id' => 'myForm', 'class' => 'pure-form'));

//but none of these does
echo $this->Form->create('Profile',array('id' => 'myForm', 'class' => 'pure-form,pure-form-aligned'));
echo $this->Form->create('Profile',array('id' => 'myForm', 'class' => {'pure-form','pure-form-aligned'}));
echo $this->Form->create('Profile',array('id' => 'myForm', 'class' => 'pure-form', 'class' => 'pure-form-aligned'));
```

How can I give html elements multiple classes using helper methods?

Comment: Please accept an answer, don't put the answer in the question that doesn't stop stackoverflow from considering the question unresolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate each css class with a space

```
'class' => 'pure-form pure-form-aligned'
```